# Zend passing string containing "Zero" to form-element Description

Tags: php, zend-framework, forms, zend-decorators

Zend talk. I built a Zend_Form class.
I noticed that if I pass the string '0' the method setDescription of my form-element will consider it as NULL  and I can't get to echo out its value in the element description.

```
//this is how I set the element description in Myform class:
$element->setDescription('0');
```

How can I avoid that?

Thanks

Luca

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php, php recognizes '0' as empty.

The Description decorator render() function checks to see if the description is empty(). There doesn't currently appear to be a way to display just a '0'.

I'd suggest filing a bug report at http://framework.zend.com/issues

Until that gets changed, your best bet is to create your own Description decorator which extends the Zend one and changes the behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I'd try either putting some whitespace around it, or disabling the auto escaping and wrapping the 0 in a span or another tag.

Comment: my decorator setting: "array('Description',array('tag'=>'h2','placement'=>'append',"escape"=>false))". none of your suggestions is working.thanks

Answer (score 0):

this is how i do it

```
abstract class Gestionale_Form_Abstract_Form extends Zend_Form
{
    protected $_myParams;//params per customizzare il form in base all'action edit/new

    public function __construct($options = null, $myParams = null)
    {
        $this->_myParams = $myParams;
        parent::__construct($options);
    }
```

....

and then for example

```
class Form_Contatto extends Gestionale_Form_Abstract_Form
...
    $clienteid->setValue($this->_myParams['data']['id']);//
```

Comment: Ho riformulato la domanda =) anche io sono di Roma.. non ci conosciamo??